# left join but keeping one observation

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two tables and wanted to left merge them. On right table, I have multiple rows and therefore, the merge result is a bigger table. In SQL, I use `HAVING` for each group and filter using max(). I am not sure how to do it in pandas.

the final table should look like :

[image]

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['k1', 2], ['k2', 3], ['k3', 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['k1', 20 , "2018-3-1"], ['k1', 30 ,"2018-3-1" ], ['k3', 60,"2018-4-1"]], columns=['A', 'C', 'Date'])
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2[['A', 'Date']], on='A', how='left')
```

Not working solution:

`df3.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x['Date']==x['Date'].max())`

Comment: `df3.groupby('A').last()` is not working too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can using `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df1.merge(df2.sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates(['A'],keep='last'),on=['A'],how='left')
    A  B     C      Date
0  k1  2  30.0  2018-3-1
1  k2  3   NaN       NaN
2  k3  6  60.0  2018-4-1
```

Or similar to SQL

```
df1.merge(df2.groupby('A',as_index=False).max(),on=['A'],how='left')
```